# python: Match string using regular expression

Tags: python, regex

I am learning regular expressions. Don't understand how to match the following pattern:

```
" myArray = ["Var1","Var2"];  "
```

Ideally I want to get the data in the array and to convert into python array

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are the array items guaranteed to be surrounded by double-quotes?

This is a quick and dirty method:

```
re.findall('"([^,]+)"', source)
```

where source is your string.
I didn't escape the double-quotes in the regex since you can also use single-quotes in Python.
This returns a list of each item surrounded by double quotes
so in your example: `['Var1', 'Var2']`

Answer (score 0):

Regular expression complexity differs much depending on variations of input. The easiest expressions that matches given string are:

```
>>> from re import search, findall
>>> s = ' myArray = ["Var1","Var2"];  '
>>> name, body = search(r'\s*(\w*)\s*=\s*\[(.*)\]', s).groups(0)
>>> contents = findall(r'"(\w*)"', body)
>>> name, contents
('myArray', ['Var1', 'Var2'])
```

"Converting" to python array can be done like this:

```
>>> globals().update({name: contents})
>>> myArray
['Var1', 'Var2']
```

Though it is actually a bad idea as it writes garbage in globals. Instead, try using separate dictionary, or something.

Comment: you could do `locals()[name] = contents`

Comment: `globals()[name] = contents` would work, but locals() are actually read only, unless you are in global scope when `locals()` and `globals()` are the same.

Answer (score 0):

If you are interested in just getting the data in the array, you can skip using regex and use eval instead.
Consider this:

```
myArray = eval('["Var1","Var2"]')
```

If you must use the line you gave in the example, you can also use exec. However this command is somewhat dangerous and needs special care if used.

Answer (score 0):

Without using an re you could use builtin string methods and `literal_eval` which given your example returns a usable `list` object:

```
from ast import literal_eval
text = ' myArray = ["Var1","Var2"];  '
name, arr_text = (el.strip('; ') for el in text.split('='))
arr  = literal_eval(arr_text)
print name, arr
```

Then do what you want with `name` and `arr`...